# Why are my Rails initializers caching ENV variables in the console (Foreman, Dev env)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, development-environment, foreman

What started as a minor annoyance has now turned into a headache. I am building a Rails 4 app and am using Foreman for my dev setup with a Procfile and .env file for configuration. When I set an ENV variable in the .env file, it is correctly picked up by my app. In this case I am setting some ENV options for Paperclip in an initializer.

The problem surfaces when I go to change the value of the ENV variables. In the console, if I type ENV["MY_VAR"], it shows the new value. However, the value that was used in my initializer, which presumably was run when I started the console, shows the old value! Nowhere in my project is the old value listed anywhere. This leads me to believe that the environment is being cached somehow or that the env variables are being exported to my shell. I'm running out of places to look so any help would be greatly appreciated! I am developing on a Mac (10.9.4) with Ruby 1.9.3-p374 and Rails 4.1.0.

Example:

ROOT/.env

```
S3_BUCKET=mybucket
```

config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = {bucket: ENV["S3_BUCKET"]}
```

If I change the value of S3_BUCKET to "newbucket" and run "foreman run rails c" or "rails c" to enter the console, this is what happens:

```
ENV["S3_BUCKET"] # => "newbucket"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] # => {bucket: 'mybucket'}
```

I should mention that this behavior also occurs in my classes that I've put in /lib. I imagine this is all due to something silly that I've overlooked. Any ideas?

Comment: If you change your env vars and want your application to pick them up, you must restart the app.  This has always been the case.

Comment: Yes, of course. To clarify though, AFTER restarting the app, the changes are not picked up in the initializers, but they are picked up in the ENV hash.

Comment: Are you using `spring` by any chance? (Check your Gemfile.)

Comment: Ah, yes, possibly. I haven't used it before so I'm not sure how you turn it on/off or configure it. However it is in my gemfile (added when I created the app) and there is a bin/spring file. Is it on by default? If so, how do I force it to reload? I also just noticed that restarting my computer resets it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4 out of the box, it comes with a gem called [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) that's *intended* to make your life easier by preloading an instance of your application in the background and reloading it as your code and configuration files change.

Spring, however, only monitors Rails' default configuration files, so you'll need to configure Spring to monitor additional any other files that you wish to trigger a reload.

Spring reads `~/.spring.rb` and `config/spring.rb` for custom settings. You can add add the following line to the file of your choosing to watch your `.env` file for changes:

```
Spring.watch '.env'
```

See [Spring's configuration documentation](https://github.com/rails/spring#configuration) in the README for more info.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Looks like I should have read the upgrade notes a bit more carefully :-).

Comment: OMFG...   I was wondering why restarting the console would not pick up the changes, even when I deleted the flipp'n file!   I had to totally shutdown the terminal.  Thank you so for this!  Absolutely maddening.

Comment: From what I can tell, config/initializers are not reloaded even with this fix. See here: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/378

Comment: Thanks! I finally got Figaro gem working again. Just added
    `Spring.watch 'config/application.yml'`

Comment: Would be a good idea to check if spring is loaded since it's often only use din development `Spring.watch('config/application.yml') if defined? Spring`